# I receive this error when I run the module

Tags: mysql

Magneto website:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table `mysite_mage1.catalog_product_entity` doesn't exist

This table exists but has a different name in my data base and it is one category further.

My table is named

```
mysite_mage1.mage_catalog_product_entity
```

I don't have access to the module's code, I cant change the name of the table it is looking for, I believe I cant I change the name of the table in mySQL database.

Comment: Lots of statements - but no question. Your quest may also be better asked here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps you could create a View in Mysql with that name that is simply `SELECT * FROM mysite_mage1.mage_catalog_product_entity;` Other than that, unless there is some config in Magneto to change it's expected table prefix, I'm not sure what you can do.

Comment: Thank you JNvill, yes he is using hard coded table names instead of getTableName(), so my database prefix is not taken into account. I think I have to rewrite these queries or cannot use the module otherwise. The only concern I have is Im not sure how to rewrite this queries without affecting the rest of my database or queries.